# lightning:input datetime remove header "date" and "time"

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to remove "date" and "time" header but I couldn't find how to do it. How can I remove them?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `variant="label-hidden"` to hide those labels and you can provide your own:

```
<div class="row slds-p-around_small">
    <h2 class="header">Basic Input Date Time</h2>
    <lightning:input variant="label-hidden" type="datetime" 
        name="input1" label="Enter a date/time value" />
</div>
```

---

Output:
[image]

---

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation) mentions about it in accessibility section:

> You must provide a text label for accessibility to make the information available to assistive technology. The label attribute creates an HTML label element for your input component. To hide a label from view and make it available to assistive technology, use the label-hidden variant.

Comment: Thank you a lot !